# Is this html input name valid: data[example[]]

Tags: php, html, php-7

- if you have many input fields and you want to insert them at once you do:

  `<input type="email" name="data[email]">`

then you insert `$_POST['data']`

- If you want to add many input fields having the same name, using
  jquery or any Js library, you do this

  `<input type="email" name="email[]"`

Then you loop through it and insert values into Mysql.

---

**My question is:** I have both scenarios; I want to insert using

`$_POST['data']` because I have many input fields, and I have a page where the user can add multiple input fields. However the following doesn't work

```
`<input type="email" name="data[email[]]">`
```

`$_POST` only has 1 row, the last one, so if the user generates 4 rows, only the last row's input fields values will be in `$_POST`.

W3 validator says that the whole page is valid, no HTML problems whatsoever.

Basically I'm appending a row of 4 input fields each time the user press add like so

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

And `var_dump($_POST[data])` is only catching the last row. `$_POST[data[])` is not valid. If I try to loop through the values I get `Warning: Illegal string offset` because there's nothing.

Is `data[example[]]` valid? Or do I have to insert each field individually, not as array?

Comment: can you show a dump of `$_POST`?

Comment: @Akintunde007 sure, I'll notify you when on pc when I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <input type="email" name="data[email[]]">
> ```

You simply got the "syntax" wrong here, this is what you want to name the fields:

```
name="data[email][]"
```

This will create an entry in `$_POST['data']['email']`, that is itself a numerically indexed array holding the individual values.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try tonight. Can I insert `$_POST[data]` directly without specifying anything?